# Default directory resides in small media while big one is empty

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

I'm very new to Ubuntu, after installing the system, the root directory, and everything decided to use the 27GB space while my main one, 290GB, remains relatively empty. Is there any way to change to the main one?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG9Am.png)

Comment: Not sure where the 27GB you mention is. Your system is on sdc7 and is only about 13.5GB. You will probably hit space problems on sdc7 quite soon just installing applications. The whole arrangement is a bit of a mess. You can go three ways. 1. Start again or 2. Move your /home to sdc6 or 3. Change to a swap file, delete sdc5 and sdc6, then expand sdc7 into the space created. I’d start again and use GPT partitions not mbr. Search on here for how to do these things there are plenty of answers or ask specific questions